# Can I extract a variable name from a vector using a for loop?

Tags: r, vector

I am practicing loops and trying to figure out how to print `___ is a good friend` if their number is odd (through an assigned number in a vector) - why won't it print the names of the people in the vector who are coded as odd numbers?

```r
B_list <- c(Bob=1, Bill=2, Buddy=3) # create character vector

phrase <- "is a good friend"

for (i in B_list){
    if((i %% 2) != 0)
        print(paste(names(i),phrase))
}
```

Output:

```
[1] " is a good friend"
[1] " is a good friend"
```

Comment: Should have been `names(B_list)[i]`. You tried to get the name of 1. It doesn't have a name, it's just a number. You should have gotten an error and then searched SO with selected parts of the error message.

Answer (score 1):

`names(listName[i])` should be used to get *the name* of the item in the list, and `listName[[i]]` should be used to get *the value* of the item in the list.

```r
B_list <- c(Bob=1, Bill=2, Buddy=3)

phrase <- "is a good friend"

for (i in B_list) {
    if((i %% 2) != 0) {
        print(paste(names(B_list[i]), phrase))
        
        print(paste("Name: ", names(B_list[i])))
        print(paste("Value: ", B_list[[i]]))
    }
}
```

The output:

```
[1] "Bob is a good friend"
[1] "Name:  Bob"
[1] "Value:  1"
[1] "Buddy is a good friend"
[1] "Name:  Buddy"
[1] "Value:  3"
```

Comment: Incredible! Thanks. Loops are new to me so very grateful for the help.